# Redundancies of an email service

Tags: php, email

This is a little bit a newbie question I know. But however I couldn't find an answer to this question.

I have made some websites that leverage the functionality of automatic emailling. I have made this websites using PHP. Every website I do, in the mailling part, I come accross some "redundancies". Let me give an example, from the examples of [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) library:

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'mail.domail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'someuser@domain.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'secret';                       
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $mail->setFrom('someuser@domain.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('to@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
```

In these two statements, is where I thought there are redundancies: `$mail->Username = "someuser@domain.com; $mail->Password = 'secret';"` and `$mail->setFrom('someuser@domain.com')`. Here is my question? Why do I need to provide a "from" address if I already given a username and password. Shoudln't it simply log in to my email account and sent it? If I provide a user name, why do I also provide a "from" address? And vice versa.

Could someone explain the reason why mailling systems work like this? I have alson seen similar structure in python's standard mailling library.

Comment: Username and Password are the credentials used to authenticate to the mail server. From is used for composing the mail. Try to formulate one clear question.

Answer (score 0):

Because "from" does not have to be the same as your log in username. You can try to send yourself a message with a different from value and check your inbox or spam folder to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

In a Microsoft Exchange server (just an example), you are able to `Send As` many users mailboxes under your mailbox login when the correct permissions are applied. So in this case, if you were using PHPMailer to send mail to a Microsoft Exchange server and authenticate, you would use the same credentials to access your mailbox, but then specify the mailbox you would like to send as in the `From` variable.

As well as the above, `From` is part of the current SMTP standard ([RFC 821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821)) and **MUST** be used when communicating with an SMTP server. So this means all mail-servers using SMTP should ask for the `From` field to meet this standard despite if they understand who is sending the email.